# Run AnimatorSet periodically causing app to freeze

Tags: java, android, performance

In my android app, i am running `Animator Set` periodically from a thread using following code

```
 mSetLeftIn = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.in_animator);



 private class OnlineStatusTimer implements Runnable {
    // @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() || objSharedPref.GetAppStringPrefByKey(R.string.session_key).equals(""))) {
            try {
                SetOnlineStatusTime();
                Thread.sleep(10000); // Pause of 10 Second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void SetOnlineStatusTime() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {                  
                if (objDriverBalStat != null && objDriverBalStat.Balance > 0) { // driver has outstanding balance to pay
                    StartAnimation(); // start animating outstanding balance layout and bike info layout
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });
}

 public void StartAnimation() {
    if (!bDateLayoutVisible) {         
        mSetLeftIn.setTarget(layoutDateBikeInfo);
        if(!mSetLeftIn.isRunning()) {
            mSetLeftIn.start();
            bDateLayoutVisible = true;
        }
  }
```

App runs fine for 2-3 mins and then start freezing. I have checked in profiler it shows `Render Thread` in CPU section running continuously.

Please suggest what could i do in this case. App starts freezing since i changed app SDK version to 33.